# Принцип работы докера

Tags: docker

[Осваиваю](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-install-and-use-docker-on-ubuntu-20-04-ru#:%7E:text=%D0%BA%D0%B0%D0%BA%20%D1%8D%D1%82%D0%BE%20%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B1%D0%BE%D1%82%D0%B0%D0%B5%D1%82.-,%D0%A8%D0%B0%D0%B3%207%20%E2%80%94%20%D0%92%D0%BD%D0%B5%D1%81%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5%20%D0%B8%D0%B7%D0%BC%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B9%20%D0%B2%20%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%BD%D1%82%D0%B5%D0%B9%D0%BD%D0%B5%D1%80%20%D0%B4%D0%BB%D1%8F%20%D0%BE%D0%B1%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B7%D0%B0%20Docker,-%D0%9F%D0%BE%D1%81%D0%BB%D0%B5%20%D0%B7%D0%B0%D0%BF%D1%83%D1%81%D0%BA%D0%B0%20%D0%BE%D0%B1%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B7%D0%B0) работу с докером и там написано:

> "После запуска образа Docker вы можете создавать, изменять и удалять файлы так же, как и с скоростью машины. Эти изменения ведутся только к контейнеру. Вы можете запустить и остановить его, но после того, как вы его уничтожите с помощью команды docker rm, изменения будут утрачены навсегда."

Получается, что я например, скачал оф.образ докера Ubuntu, поставил на него программы (Python, NGINX, MYSQL), потом сохранил под своим именем и запустил егона другой машине.

Если, например, мой скрипт создает файлы (например, f1.txt, f2.txt) и дирректории (например, dir1, dir2), то если я остановлю работу этого докера через:

```
sudo docker stop [CONTAINER ID]
```

а потом если запущу, то файлов (f1.txt, f2.txt) и директорий (dir1, dir2) уже не будет созданных тем приложением?

Или я то-то не так понял?

Comment: Я не знаток докера, но, по-моему там написано, что изменения, сделанные внутри конкретного контейнера, остаются в нём же. И если удалить этот контейнер, то изменения потеряются. И дальше описано, как сохранить изменения контейнера в новый образ, чтобы кому-нибудь этот образ передать, например. Ну или чтобы эти изменения у вас сразу были при запуске этого образа с новым контейнером (я могу путаться в терминологии).

Comment: "_поставил на него программы (Python, NGINX, MYSQL)_" Это противоречит концепции докера. Один контейнер - один главный процесс. В вашем случае у вас 3 контейнера: nginx, mysql и ваше приложение на питоне. И общаются эти 3 контейнера между собой только по сети, по адресам контейнеров. Если вам нужно что бы файлы гарантированно оставались даже после пересоздания контейнеров (например база данных), то на нужные точки контейнеров вы монтируете внешние файловые системы (папки основной машины или volume докера)

Comment: @MIke, т.е. я должен скачать 4 образа докера: Ubuntu, Nginx, Mysql, python? и как-то их связывать между собой? В файле запуска прописать команды что надо запустить 4 файла + прописать команды на установку необходимых библиотек?

Comment: «как и с скоростью машины» — мне хочется плакать от этого перевода

Comment: @АлексейБелкин nginx, mysql, python — да, а зачем нужен образ ubuntu, если вы и так уже скачали три других образа, не очень понятно. Установка необходимых библиотек прописывается в Dockerfile (или каком-нибудь его аналоге), который соберёт новый образ с вашей программой, содержащий в себе все нужные ей библиотеки

Comment: @АлексейБелкин Ubuntu вам не нужен. он скачается автоматически и будет использован всеми тремя образами (если конечно вы для всех 3х контейнеров используете образы на основе Ubuntu).

Comment: @АлексейБелкин Да и специально скачивать не всегда надо. Вот например у меня есть файл запуска БД postgresql для отладочной базы. `sudo docker run --name dev-postgres -it -v /home/mike/postgres/data:/var/lib/postgresql/data --net devel --ip 172.18.0.2 -e "TZ=Europe/Moscow" -e POSTGRES_PASSWORD=123 postgres:alpine` при ее запуске образ postgres:alpine будет автоматически скачан, если это не делалось ранее, на основе него будет создан контейнер, в котором будет БД из каталога /home/mike/postgres/data самой машины. После этого postgres будет доступен на адресе 172.18.0.2

Comment: Если БД еще не было, то она будет создана в указанной директории и установлен пароль для пользователя postgres 123

Comment: Чтобы Ubuntu автоматически скачался - мне надо это будет прописать в докерфайле?

Comment: Он скачается в любом случае, указываете вы его в докерфайле в FROM или прямо используете в команде docker run. Обратите внимание, для постгреса я даже не создавал собственного Dockerfile а использовал готовый базовый образ, без изменений

Comment: А вообще для любого общедоступного образа читайте документацию на hub.doker.com там написано как именно работать с этим образом, какие параметры передавать при запуске, где лучше размещать конфиги и другие файлы для него. например mysql https://hub.docker.com/_/mysql

Comment: Получается, что скачивание образов для докера не нужно? Они скачиваются только для подстраховки на тот случай, что если их вдруг не окажется (ну или для экономии времени)? Значит можно просто один докер файл создать и в нем все прописать: от скачивания образов до настройки их?

Comment: `FROM ...` автоматом скачивает образ, либо берет его из кеша системы. Если у вас `FROM nginx:latest`, вторая и следующая пересборка будут использовать кеш системы. Хотите обновить? `docker pull nginx:latest` в командной строке. Также лучше использовать конкретные версии `nginx:1.23.1` - так как программы имеют свойство меняться, и то, что работало раньше, в новой версии может работать перестать. Ну Nginx с этим вряд ли будут проблемы, а вот с python - вполне себе да.

Comment: PS. Вообще `docker pull --help` дает конкретный ответ - получить образ из реестра. Есть проблема кеширования, и это команда ее решает.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Нужно понимать, чем образ отличается от контейнера.

> Получается, что я например, скачал оф.образ докера Ubuntu, поставил на него программы (Python, NGINX, MYSQL), потом сохранил под своим именем и запустил его на другой машине.

Если сохранили образ (`docker build` или `docker commit`), то все файлы сохранятся и будут доступны везде, где будет запущен образ (`docker run`). Контейнеры же создаются из образов, функционируют и умирают, теряя все свои данные - это концепция. Чтобы обмениваться образами, есть репозитории, например https://hub.docker.com

> если я остановлю ...
> sudo docker stop ...
> а потом если запущу

Файлы останутся. Остановка контейнера (`docker start`) - все слои файловой системы остаются на месте, данные не теряются. Но не перепутайте с запуском нового контейнера (`docker run`) на основе образа - там файлов не будет.

Удаление контейнера (`docker stop`, затем `docker rm`)- слои удаются, данные теряются.

Исключение: если данные сохраняются в volume (томах), которые подмонтированы в контейнер, они останутся.

Comment: еще уточнение. Как правильно делать:
1) Поставить программы, создать директории проекта, залить туда проект, создать пользователей, виртуальное окружение и библиотеки и потом сохранить образ докера, а в файле запуска только указать как запустить докер
или
2) Постаить только программы, а в файле запуска докера  прописать команды того, что написано выше?

Comment: @АлексейБелкин Это зависит от того, для каких целей используется контейнер. В любом случае лучше иметь минимум 2 образа: базовый, в котором уже стоят программы и все библиотеки (он обычно очень долго собирается) и второй образ - с самим приложением, как наследник от этого базового образа. Если контейнер используется для разработки, то его удобно запускать на базовом образе и монтировать папки с приложением внутрь. А если это какой нибудь продакт или пре-продакт, то создается второй образ внутри которого в дополнение к базовому копируются файлы проекта

Comment: @АлексейБелкин, данные (те же пользователи) вообще должны быть отдельно от образа/контейнера, контейнер должен только знать, как к базе подключиться (например, искать данные подключения в переменных окружения).